# macOS Big Sur 11.6.7 update: many apps require Rosetta

Tags: upgrade, big-sur, rosetta

I just updated my Macbook pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) from Big Sur 11.6.6 to 11.6.7 and now, all the Intel apps require Rosetta.
[image: Whatsapp info]

[image: Rosetta request]

- Why such a big change between two minor versions?
- Is there a way to avoid installing Rosetta?
- Can I downgrade back to 11.6.6?

Comment: Could it be that those apps are Universal apps but are configured to open using Rosetta (see https://support.apple.com/HT211861)? Intel-only apps always require Rosetta on an Apple silicon Mac.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are "Intel app" but they opened seamlessly until the last update.

Comment: If they are Intel apps and they worked the they ran through rosetta. Perhaps a cache has changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application you have shown is Intel only. It MUST have run under Rosetta before.

A point update should not normally require a re-installation of Rosetta, but it's nothing to worry about.

A Universal Binary application will show Get Info like this:

[image]

Keep watching out for updates to your apps, as developers produce Universal Binaries for both Intel and ARM.

Comment: After reinstalling Rosetta, everything is working well...